# twitter bootstrap modal automatically focus on first text field

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the latest version of twitter bootstrap (v3.1.1). For some reason I can't get it to focus on the first text field. Here's what I tried so far:

add `autofocus` attribute on the text field. This works but only for the first time. The second time I try to call `$el.modal('show')` again it no longer focuses on the text field with the `autofocus` attribute.

blur the button that was clicked to trigger the showing of modal and then call `.focus` on the text field where I want the focus:

```
$('#btn-link').click(function(){
    $('#btn-link').blur();
    $('#link-modal').modal('show');
    $('#link_url').focus();
});
```

The above one doesn't work either.

Lastly I tried the following:

```
$("#link-modal").on('shown', function(){ //also tried on 'show'
    console.log('yo');
    document.activeElement.blur();
    $(this).find(".modal-body :input:visible").first().focus();
});
```

But this one doesn't work either, it doesn't focus on the text field and it doesn't even execute the `console.log`.
Am I doing something wrong here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: can u set up a fiddle?

Answer (score 3):

ok I got it working, seems like I had to use the past participle form `shown` instead of just `show`:

```
$('#link-modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function(){
  $('#link_url').focus();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap 3 and above u need to use this...

```
 $('#link-modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
         document.activeElement.blur();
         $(this).find(".modal-body :input:visible").first().focus();
    });
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to be working either, though its executing the code inside when the modal shows up the text field that I want doesn't get the focus.

Comment: You should use 'shown.bs.modal' instead of 'show.bs.modal'.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got this working in my webform .aspx page.  In my modal I have a multiline asp:TextBox called "uxComment" that I  want to have focus when the modal is popped up.  Here is the script that I had to add to my .aspx page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function openCommentModal() {
        $('#uxCommentModal').modal('show');

        $('#uxCommentModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {            
            $('#<%= uxComment.ClientID %>').focus();
        });
    }
</script>
```

Here is the code for my modal:

```
<div id="uxCommentModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">                              
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">                                                        
                        <h4 class="modal-title text-center">Add New Comment</h4><hr />
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">   
                        <div class="row">                                
                            <div class="form-group col-sm-12">  
                                <label for="uxComment">Comment:</label>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="uxComment" runat="server" Rows="25" TextMode="MultiLine" CssClass="form-control" />                                                      

                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="uxAddNewCommentRequired" runat="server"
                                    Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="uxComment" 
                                    ValidationGroup="addComment" CssClass="text-danger">
                                    <br />(Comment required)
                                </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

                                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="uxAddNewCommentValidator" 
                                    runat="server" Display="Dynamic" 
                                    ControlToValidate="uxComment" CssClass="text-danger"
                                    ValidationExpression="^((.|\n){0,5000})$"
                                    ValidationGroup="addComment">
                                    <br />(Comment cannot exceed 5000 characters)
                                    </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                            </div>                                
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-9">
                                <button type="button" id="uxCancelComment" runat="server" class="btn btn-default" onserverclick="uxCancelComment_Click" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                                <asp:Button ID="uxSubmitComment" runat="server" Text="Add Comment" 
                                    CssClass="btn btn-primary" 
                                    OnClick="uxSubmitComment_Click" CausesValidation="true" 
                                    ValidationGroup="addComment" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>   
            </div>
        </div>
```

I pop up the modal on a asp:Button click event seen here:

```
protected void uxCommentAddButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Pop", "openCommentModal();", true);
}
```

I hope this helps someone still using webforms.  I spent several hours on this!